# what is the keycode for backspace

Tags: python, python-2.7, xbmc

I'm working on my python script as I have input the keyboard code in the script.

I can get the up, down, left, right and ESC keycode to work when I press the buttons on the keyboard, but I can't get the backspace to work using `ACTION_PARENT_DIR = 9` when I press on the backspace button on the keyboard.

Here is the test.py:

```
import xbmc 
import xbmcgui

#get actioncodes from keymap.xml
ACTION_MOVE_LEFT = 1
ACTION_MOVE_RIGHT = 2
ACTION_MOVE_UP = 3
ACTION_MOVE_DOWN = 4
ACTION_PARENT_DIR = 9
ACTION_PREVIOUS_MENU = 10

class MyClass(xbmcgui.WindowXML):
  def onAction(self, action):

    if action == ACTION_PREVIOUS_MENU:
         self.close()

    if action == ACTION_PARENT_DIR:
         self.close()    


    if action == ACTION_MOVE_LEFT:
         self.strAction = xbmcgui.ControlLabel(300, 200, 600, 200, '', 'font14', '0xFF00FF00')
         self.addControl(self.strAction)
         self.strAction.setLabel('You have press on the left arrow button!')

    if action == ACTION_MOVE_RIGHT:
         self.removeControl(self.strAction)
         self.strAction = xbmcgui.ControlLabel(300, 200, 600, 200, '', 'font14', '0xFF00FF00')
         self.addControl(self.strAction)
         self.strAction.setLabel('You have press on the right arrow button!')


    if action == ACTION_MOVE_UP:
         self.strAction = xbmcgui.ControlLabel(300, 200, 600, 200, '', 'font14', '0xFF00FF00')
         self.addControl(self.strAction)
         self.strAction.setLabel('You have press on the up arrow button!')

    if action == ACTION_MOVE_DOWN:

         self.strAction = xbmcgui.ControlLabel(300, 200, 600, 200, '', 'font14', '0xFF00FF00')
         self.addControl(self.strAction)
         self.strAction.setLabel('You have press on the down arrow button!')
```

And here is the keycode.xml

```
<keymap>
  <global>
    <keyboard>
      <p>Play</p>
      <q>Queue</q>
      <f>FastForward</f>
      <r>Rewind</r>
      <left>Left</left>
      <right>Right</right>
      <up>Up</up>
      <down>Down</down>
      <left mod="ctrl">analogseekback</left>
      <right mod="ctrl">analogseekforward</right>
      <pageup>PageUp</pageup>
      <pagedown>PageDown</pagedown>
      <return>Select</return>
      <enter>Select</enter>
      <delete>Back</delete>
      <backspace>Back</backspace>
      <key id="65446">Back</key>
      <m>ActivateWindow(PlayerControls)</m>
      <s>ActivateWindow(shutdownmenu)</s>
      <escape>PreviousMenu</escape>
      <key id="61952">parentdir</key>
      <i>Info</i>
      <menu>ContextMenu</menu>
      <c>ContextMenu</c>
      <space>Pause</space>
      <x>Stop</x>
      <period>SkipNext</period>
      <comma>SkipPrevious</comma>
      <tab>FullScreen</tab>
      <printscreen>Screenshot</printscreen>
      <s mod="ctrl">Screenshot</s>
      <minus>VolumeDown</minus>
      <plus>VolumeUp</plus>
      <equals>VolumeUp</equals>
      <zero>Number0</zero>
      <one>Number1</one>
      <two>Number2</two>
      <three>Number3</three>
      <four>Number4</four>
      <five>Number5</five>
      <six>Number6</six>
      <seven>Number7</seven>
      <eight>Number8</eight>
      <nine>Number9</nine>
      <numpadminus>VolumeDown</numpadminus>
      <numpadplus>VolumeUp</numpadplus>
      <numpadzero>Number0</numpadzero>
      <numpadone>Number1</numpadone>
      <numpadtwo>Number2</numpadtwo>
      <numpadthree>Number3</numpadthree>
      <numpadfour>Number4</numpadfour>
      <numpadfive>Number5</numpadfive>
      <numpadsix>Number6</numpadsix>
      <numpadseven>Number7</numpadseven>
      <numpadeight>Number8</numpadeight>
      <numpadnine>Number9</numpadnine>
      <backslash>ToggleFullScreen</backslash>
      <home>FirstPage</home>
      <end>LastPage</end>
      <!-- Multimedia keyboard keys -->
      <browser_back>Back</browser_back>
      <browser_forward></browser_forward>
      <browser_refresh></browser_refresh>
      <browser_stop></browser_stop>
      <browser_search></browser_search>
      <browser_favorites>ActivateWindow(Favourites)</browser_favorites>
      <browser_home>XBMC.ActivateWindow(Home)</browser_home>
      <volume_mute>Mute</volume_mute>
      <volume_down>VolumeDown</volume_down>
      <volume_up>VolumeUp</volume_up>
      <next_track>SkipNext</next_track>
      <prev_track>SkipPrevious</prev_track>
      <stop>Stop</stop>
      <play_pause>Pause</play_pause>
      <launch_mail></launch_mail>
      <launch_media_select>XBMC.ActivateWindow(MyMusic)</launch_media_select>
      <launch_app1_pc_icon>ActivateWindow(MyPrograms)</launch_app1_pc_icon>
      <launch_app2_pc_icon>ActivateWindow(MyPrograms)</launch_app2_pc_icon>
      <launch_file_browser></launch_file_browser>
      <launch_media_center></launch_media_center>
      <!-- ****************************************************** -->
      <!-- MS Media Center keyboard shortcuts sent by MCE remotes -->
      <!-- See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb189249.aspx -->
      <p mod="ctrl,shift">Play</p>
      <!-- Play -->
      <s mod="ctrl,shift">Stop</s>
      <!-- Stop -->
      <p mod="ctrl">Pause</p>
      <!-- Pause -->
      <f mod="ctrl,shift">FastForward</f>
      <!-- Fwd -->
      <b mod="ctrl,shift">Rewind</b>
      <!-- Rew -->
      <f mod="ctrl">SkipNext</f>
      <!-- Skip -->
      <b mod="ctrl">SkipPrevious</b>
      <!-- Replay -->
      <d mod="ctrl">Info</d>
      <!-- MCE Details -->
      <f10>VolumeUp</f10>
      <!-- MCE Vol up -->
      <f9>VolumeDown</f9>
      <!-- MCE Vol down -->
      <f8>Mute</f8>
      <!-- MCE mute -->
      <g mod="ctrl">OSD</g>
      <!-- MCE Guide -->
      <m mod="ctrl">ActivateWindow(music)</m>
      <!-- MCE My music -->
      <i mod="ctrl">ActivateWindow(pictures)</i>
      <!-- MCE My pictures -->
      <e mod="ctrl">ActivateWindow(video)</e>
      <!-- MCE videos -->
      <m mod="ctrl,shift">PlayerControl(ShowVideoMenu)</m>
      <!-- MCE DVD menu -->
      <!-- MCE keypresses without an obvious use in XBMC -->
      <o mod="ctrl">Notification(MCEKeypress, Recorded TV, 3)</o>
      <t mod="ctrl">Notification(MCEKeypress, Live TV, 3)</t>
      <t mod="ctrl,shift">Notification(MCEKeypress, My TV, 3)</t>
      <a mod="ctrl">Notification(MCEKeypress, Radio, 3)</a>
      <u mod="ctrl">Notification(MCEKeypress, DVD subtitle, 3)</u>
      <a mod="ctrl,shift">Notification(MCEKeypress, DVD audio, 3)</a>
    </keyboard>
  </global>
  <loginscreen>
    <keyboard>
      <end>XBMC.ShutDown()</end>
    </keyboard>
  </loginscreen>
  <home>
    <keyboard>
      <i>info</i>
      <end>XBMC.ShutDown()</end>
    </keyboard>
  </home>
  <virtualkeyboard>
    <keyboard>
      <backspace>Backspace</backspace>
    </keyboard>
  </virtualkeyboard>
</keymap>
```

Does anyone know what keycode I should use to get the backspace to work on xbmc?

I need the backspace to work when I press on the keyboard, because I want to go back to the previous main menu when I press backspace on the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

ID for backspace-key (which is mapped to the "back" action) is `92`.

I wrote a small add-on to get the IDs for a given action: https://github.com/dersphere/script.get_action_id

Just clone or download this repository to your xbmc/addons/ dir, you will find it under program-plugins.